# Provided script throws error while executiong-Grep unmatched

Tags: shell

Guys when i run the below script I get error grep: Unmatched ( or (

Also Iam unable to understand the grep performed in the shell script for fetching the definition of a word from web.

```
#!/bin/sh

# define - given a word, return its definition from dictionary.com

url="http://www.cogsci.princeton.edu/cgi-bin/webwn2.0?stage=1&word="

if [ $# -ne 1 ] ; then
echo "Usage: $0 word" >&2 
exit 1
fi

lynx -source "$url$1" | \
grep -E '(^[[:digit:]]+\.| has [[:digit:]]+$)' | \
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' |
( while read line 
do 
if [ "${line:0:3}" = "The" ] ; then
  part="$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')"
  echo ""
  echo "The $part $1:"
else
  echo "$line" | fmt | sed 's/^/  /g'
fi
done
) 

exit 0
```

Comment: `"has"` -- what's that about? (e.g. `'...  has [[:digit:]]+$)'`)

Comment: `sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' | ` missing backslash at the end of the line?